# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined react + webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have been working on a project for about 2 months and used [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware).

According to the WDM documentation, its just a wrapper for webpack and run the project in the memory to enable hot reloading.

But now when im trying to build and deploy with webpack and same webpack.config.js i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error.

I have searched alot and couldn't find a right answer for my case.

I'd really appreciate any help :).

my webpack.config.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {

  entry: './src/client.js',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  target: 'web',

  // keep node_module paths out of the bundle
  externals: fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')).concat([
    'react-dom/server', 'react/addons',
  ]).reduce(function (ext, mod) {
    ext[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod
    return ext
  }, {}),

  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&name=/[hash].[ext]',
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader"}
    ],
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'

}
```

I'm using webpack version : 1.13.3 as local.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong, where are you getting this error exactly? when you build your project, or when you open it with a browser?

Comment: When i build, it will finish building successfully
But when i run it in the browser, i see the error

Answer (score 0):

In my case reason was:

`...
  module: {
    noParse: /\.min\.js$/,
...`

I've commented it out